# Sum some specific rows from a column like Excel can do

Tags: r, excel

I have a (for me) hard task to solve.
I'm working with precipitation data and want to build some SumS for evaulation with a heavy rain Index regarding different timescales.

I got a version of this in Excel, but i wanna automate the process.
Here is what Excel is doing:

[image]

(First Post here, i don't realy know how to implement the Excel vision in Text here...Thats why the link to the png)

Finaly i aim for this.
THe Program shall read the import csv, which just contains 2 colums, (Date and precipitation in mm).
Then it shall add columns for different timescales (like in the Image) In the IMage you can see the excel "code" for the marked cell. It summs 5 cells from the precipitation column. I would prefer doing this backwards so it should be =SUM(B6:B10) In case of 10 min column that shuld be B1:B10 and so on.... In the End i want to get the max values out of the new columns which stand for the Maximum precipitation fallen within 5,10,15,20 or 60 mins.

Problem:
I did not find a way to get the sum of the rows in the precipitation column.. Always some dimension errors or other mistakes. For example i tried this:

```
data <- <- read.csv(file = file.choose(),sep=';')
data$d5 <-0
data$d10 <-0
for (i in 2:nrow(data)) {
  n <- rowSums(Daata$precip.in.mm[i-1:i,])
  data$D5[i] <- n
```

In this case hes compaining about the Dimensions. I don't rly see the Problem...

Would be awesome if someone could help me solve this..i guess... rly easy (not for me) task.

Thank you for reading and helping!

Comment: You could further help us by giving us an example of the data. After loading the csv, type `dput(head(data,18))`. This will print a text to the terminal, which you can then copy into your question. This text contains the first 18 rows of your data for us to replicate easily.

Comment: The import csv just contains of the columns A and B from the picture. C, D, E,... shall be written by the program (like i did with data$d5 <-0 and renamed in the end).
Date                   Precip [mm]
07.08.2021 12:05 0
07.08.2021 12:06 0
07.08.2021 12:07 0
07.08.2021 12:08 0
07.08.2021 12:09 0
07.08.2021 12:10 0
07.08.2021 12:11 0
07.08.2021 12:12 0
07.08.2021 12:13 0
07.08.2021 12:14 0
07.08.2021 12:15 0
07.08.2021 12:16 0
07.08.2021 12:17 0
07.08.2021 12:18 0
07.08.2021 12:19 0
07.08.2021 12:20 0
07.08.2021 12:21 0

Comment: Could you please elaborate how the last measurements are to be handled. `D=5Min` sums up the precipitation for the nex 5 minutes. but what shall it do, when there are no 5 Minutes Left in the timeline? Should it display NA or just sum up the remaining, but fewer than 5 Values?

Comment: I guess the remainig Data would be the best. For my work i would extract the data with a few hours around the heavy rain event so that the first 120 and the last 120 rows of the data in the timeline are not sooo much important for extracting the max value.

Answer (score 0):

You want a so called window function. These roll over a vector and aggregate values on those vectors. There are a few packages that can handle this, like `zoo`  with `rollapply`.

I have written a base R function that handles this:

```r
window_roll_sum <- function(sorted_input, # Sorted input Vector
                            n=5 # Window size
                            ){
  input_length <- length(sorted_input)
  res <- sapply(1:input_length, #from 1 to input length
                function(x){ # define current pos as x
                  sum(sorted_input[ #sum up the input from x
                    x:(x+min( #to x+window
                        n,
                        input_length-x
                        ) # if remaining vector to small for window
                       # sum up two last value (input length)
                      )
                  ])# end sum
                }# end function
          )
  return(res)
}
```

Now you can apply this function to your Data.

```r
data$d5 <- window_roll_sum(data$precip.in.mm, n=5)
```

**Important**: This function assumes a vector sorted by time and with the same distance of time between measurements, as it blindly sums up the following `n` measurements of the vector.

Comment: First, realy realy Thank you for spending youre time with this task.
I implemented your Code in mine but therer is a problem i guess. the 3rd colum i create in the beginning data$D5 <- 0 is untouched, there are only 0 in the whole column. the function don't sum the values. I guess it worked in your code, so there must be a mistake in my data or the other part of the code...

Comment: I guess the first mistake was that the import file hast text in the first row.
I deleted the Text and R could run everything. Now the Problem is, that in the new Column, every second value is NA and the rest is 0

Comment: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables

that's what i get all the Time